# Decoding ifIndex is not returning any values

Tags: snmp

I am setting up 4 Westermo switches and therefore I am making some software changes in C to decode the MIB packets. I am using IReasoning MIB Browser (RFC 1213) for this.

I am trying to get information from ifIndex (.1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1) but unfortunately I am not getting any data/values when I try to decode this OID. I am expecting data like 1,2,3,4,4096,4097,4098 etc which represents the port numbers for a switch.

However, I am able to decode other OIDs e.g sysDescr, sysUpTime, sysName, sysLocation, ifNumber, ifOperStatus.

Is there any additional checking that has to be done in C(which I have missed) although iReasoning MIB Browser displays this information when double clicked on it OR when I select to view in Table View.

Please advise.

Comment: Are you using SNMP-get or SNMP-walk? Get is used to get a scalar value but ifIndex is a table so you have to use walk.

Comment: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1213 `ifIndex`'s value (by the standard) might not match the port numbers. Of course, the vendor might not even look at the standard.

Comment: @user1793963: Thanks for pointing that out. I was using Get command which explains my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me, on the Lynx 210 on my desk, using the following command

```
snmpwalk -v2c -r5 -t3 -cpublic 192.168.2.200 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2
IF-MIB::ifIndex.1 = INTEGER: 1
IF-MIB::ifIndex.17 = INTEGER: 17
IF-MIB::ifIndex.18 = INTEGER: 18
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4096 = INTEGER: 4096
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4097 = INTEGER: 4097
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4098 = INTEGER: 4098
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4099 = INTEGER: 4099
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4100 = INTEGER: 4100
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4101 = INTEGER: 4101
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4102 = INTEGER: 4102
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4103 = INTEGER: 4103
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4104 = INTEGER: 4104
IF-MIB::ifIndex.4105 = INTEGER: 4105
```

Comment: Also, using the ifIndex to reference interfaces/ports is usually fragile.  It is better to use the port label (WeOS) or the interface name.  http://serverfault.com/questions/167520/linux-ifindex-persistence-for-snmp

As you may have noticed, WeOS ports (Layer-2) start with an ifIndex of 4096 and regular interfaces (Layer-3) start at 1 (loopback).  Then, depending on if you change configuration at runtime, you will get different ifIndex for the Layer-3 interfaces as they are enumerated by the underlying Linux kernel.